# setContentOffset loses precision?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have an application where I need to initialize the `contentOffset` of a `UIScrollView` to a certain value. I notice when I set the `contentOffset`, it rounds the points up to the nearest integers. I've tried using both `setContentOffset` and `setContentOffset:animated` and still get the same result. When I try to manually add the `contentOffset` onto the frame origin, I don't get the result I want. Anyone know anyway around this?

```
UIScrollView *myScrollViewTemp = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(CropThePhotoViewControllerScrollViewBorderWidth, CropThePhotoViewControllerScrollViewBorderWidth, self.myScrollViewBorderView.frame.size.width - (CropThePhotoViewControllerScrollViewBorderWidth * 2), self.myScrollViewBorderView.frame.size.height - (CropThePhotoViewControllerScrollViewBorderWidth * 2))];
[self setMyScrollView: myScrollViewTemp];
[[self myScrollView] setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[[self myScrollView] setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator: NO];
[[self myScrollView] setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator: NO];
[[self myScrollView] setBouncesZoom: YES];
[[self myScrollView] setDecelerationRate: UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast];
[[self myScrollView] setDelegate:self];
[[self myScrollViewBorderView] addSubview: [self myScrollView]];
[myScrollViewTemp release];

UIImageView *myImageViewTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: self.myImage];
[self setMyImageView: myImageViewTemp];
[[self myScrollView] addSubview:[self myImageView]];
[[self myScrollView] setContentSize: [self.myImage size]];
[[self myScrollView] setMinimumZoomScale: self.previousZoomScale];
[[self myScrollView] setMaximumZoomScale: 10];
[[self myScrollView] setZoomScale: self.previousZoomScale animated:NO];
[[self myScrollView] setContentOffset: self.contentOffset animated:NO];
[myImageViewTemp release];
```

UPDATE: Updated code.

Comment: Does it round up even on retina devices? If so, that seems like a bug. If it only rounds on non-retina devices, this is to be expected. UIScrollView wants its content pixel aligned.

Comment: I have an iPhone 4 so yes I believe that is a retina device. Thing is, the value I'm trying to set the contentOffset to, is a contentOffset that I copied from another UIScrollView where I was moving around an image. So it's capable of scrolling to a half point, but when I set it it rounds up?

Comment: @meronix - put some code, don't know if it will help

Comment: I have written some test code and cannot reproduce this. Setting a half-pixel offset works fine for me.

Comment: actually check that, still getting the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this isn't a bug on my part, but is the intended behavior by Apple whether on purpose or not. In order to work around this, you need to set the contentOffset in the viewWillLayoutSubviews method of the UIViewController. Apparently, you need to set the contentOffset after the whole view frame has been set.

Comment: Hey, could you share more on how you got that information? I'm having the same issue, but obviously not the same setup, so a bit more info would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I too struggled with this issue quite a bit, but it turns out that you could just set the bounds on the scroll view, which does the same thing and actually deals ok with CGFloat values.

```
CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(3.8, 0);
```

We got the new offset here.

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset];
```

After this line the current offset is (4,0).

```
scrollView.bounds = CGRectMake(newOffset.x, newOffset.y, scrollView.bounds.size.width, scrollView.bounds.size.height);
```

And this gives you (3.8, 0)

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 4:

I've maded an extension to have more precision:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func setPreciseContentOffset( x:CGFloat? = nil, y:CGFloat? = nil, animated:Bool,completion:@escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
        var myX:CGFloat = self.contentOffset.x
        var myY:CGFloat = self.contentOffset.y
        if let x = x {
            myX = x
        }
        if let y = y {
            myY = y
        }
        let point = CGPoint(x:myX,y:myY)
        if animated {
            // calculate duration
            var duration = 0.25 // min duration
            let destCoord =  myX != self.contentOffset.x ? myX : myY
            let diff = fabs ( self.contentOffset.x - destCoord)
            duration += TimeInterval(diff) / 1000
            UIView.animate(withDuration:duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                self.bounds = CGRect(x:point.x,y:point.y,width: self.bounds.size.width,height: self.bounds.size.height)
            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                completion(finished)
            })
        } else {
            self.bounds = CGRect(x:point.x,y:point.y,width: self.bounds.size.width,height: self.bounds.size.height)
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
// supposing you have to scroll manually in horizontal

self.myScrollview.setPreciseContentOffset(x:contentX, animated: true, completion: {[weak self] _ in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
        // HERE the scroll is ended, pay attention the end scrolling delegates aren't be called  because you set manually self.bounds so HERE implement your scrolling end code
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the contents of any subviews of the UIScrollView would be rendered blurred if the contentOffset is not rounded up, especially text.

Comment: The CGPoint that I'm setting the contentOffset to is actually a contentOffset that I collected from a previous UIScrollView on a different controller. So the UIScrollView itself set it to non integer when I was scrolling it.

Comment: Retina displays can render half-point offsets and still be pixel-aligned (i.e. no blurring). So it should not be rounding really.

Comment: It's `round(coordinate*contentscale)/contentscale`, I guess.